# How to use EndpointSecurity API properly in MacOS 10.15?

Tags: macos

I added entitlement and disable SIP :com.apple.developer.endpoint-security.client still get `ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED`,How to use
    EndpointSecurity API properly under Xcode 11?Do I need to run as root？

Code for your reference:

```
#import <EndpointSecurity/EndpointSecurity.h>

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    es_client_t *client;

    es_new_client_result_t res = es_new_client(&client, ^(es_client_t *client, const es_message_t *message) {
        NSLog(@"Hi");
    });

    if (res == ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_SUCCESS){
        NSApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor.CGColor;
        NSLog(@"ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_SUCCESS");
    }else if(res == ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_INTERNAL){
        NSLog(@"ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_INTERNAL");
    }else if(res == ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_ENTITLED){
        NSLog(@"ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_ENTITLED");
    }else if(res == ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED){
        NSLog(@"ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED");
    }else if(res == ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT){
        NSLog(@"ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT");
    }

    BOOL isSubscribeSuccess = es_subscribe(client, ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_OPEN);
    if (isSubscribeSuccess == true){
        NSLog(@"isSubscribeSuccess");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"SubscribeErrpr");
    }

    }
```

In entitlements:

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.endpoint-security.client</key>
    <true/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you need is run as root.
Or set the debug process as root by tweaking scheme settings. (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...)

[image: Screenshot of Edit Scheme Panel]

Comment: My app crashes immediately If I run it as root, probably an issue with sandbox?

Comment: I think this answer confuses two errors. The requirement to run as root is indicated by  `ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PRIVILEGED`. The question is about another error, `ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED`.

Answer (score 1):

According to `EndpointSecurity/ESTypes.h`:

> ///The caller is not permitted to connect. They lack Transparency,
>   Consent, and Control (TCC) approval form the user.

So, `ES_NEW_CLIENT_RESULT_ERR_NOT_PERMITTED` indicates that your process was not approved by the user as is required for using EndpointSecurity API. The documentation for `es_new_client` in `EndpointSecurity/ESClient.h` states:

> The application calling this interface must also be approved by users
>   via Transparency, Consent & Control (TCC) mechanisms using
>   the Privacy Preferences pane and adding the application to Full Disk
>   Access.

A dialog asking the user for permission should come up automatically when you call EndpointSecurity API from a system extension. Otherwise, the user must allow its use manually. BTW, for testing purposes with a command line tool calling EndpointSecurity API I had to add Terminal to Full Disk Access.